# Why does pandas market calendar give "ValueError: The dtype of 'values' is incorrect. Must be 'datetime64[ns]'. Got object instead."?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

The pandas-market-calendars module documentation gives a quickstart example of how to create a schedule here: https://pypi.org/project/pandas-market-calendars/

I copy-pasted their quickstart example:

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

# Create a calendar
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')

# Show available calendars
print(mcal.get_calendar_names())

early = nyse.schedule(start_date='2012-07-01', end_date='2012-07-10')
print(early)
```

In their example, we should get a nice pretty schedule output:

```
                  market_open             market_close
=========== ========================= =========================
 2012-07-02 2012-07-02 13:30:00+00:00 2012-07-02 20:00:00+00:00
 2012-07-03 2012-07-03 13:30:00+00:00 2012-07-03 17:00:00+00:00
 2012-07-05 2012-07-05 13:30:00+00:00 2012-07-05 20:00:00+00:00
 2012-07-06 2012-07-06 13:30:00+00:00 2012-07-06 20:00:00+00:00
 2012-07-09 2012-07-09 13:30:00+00:00 2012-07-09 20:00:00+00:00
 2012-07-10 2012-07-10 13:30:00+00:00 2012-07-10 20:00:00+00:00
```

instead, I get an error:
ValueError: The dtype of 'values' is incorrect. Must be 'datetime64[ns]'. Got object instead.

What am I doing wrong? I thought I input the dates exactly like the example showed. Why is it requiring a different format? Some people have ran the above code without error. My traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Strawberry/Strawberry_Omega/tests/pandas_mkt_clndr_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    early = nyse.schedule(start_date='2012-07-01', end_date='2012-07-10')
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas_market_calendars\market_calendar.py", line 632, in schedule
    adjusted = schedule.loc[_close_adj].apply(
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7547, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 180, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 255, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 284, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas_market_calendars\market_calendar.py", line 633, in <lambda>
    lambda x: x.where(x.le(x["market_close"]), x["market_close"]), axis= 1)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 9001, in where
    return self._where(
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8741, in _where
    cond, _ = cond.align(self, join="right", broadcast_axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4274, in align
    return super().align(
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8556, in align
    return self._align_series(
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8664, in _align_series
    right = other._reindex_indexer(join_index, ridx, copy)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4241, in _reindex_indexer
    return self.copy()
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5660, in copy
    data = self._mgr.copy(deep=deep)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 802, in copy
    res = self.apply("copy", deep=deep)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 406, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 679, in copy
    return self.make_block_same_class(values, ndim=self.ndim)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 261, in make_block_same_class
    return type(self)(values, placement=placement, ndim=ndim)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 1544, in __init__
    values = self._maybe_coerce_values(values)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2170, in _maybe_coerce_values
    values = self._holder(values)
  File "C:\Users\Wes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 254, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The dtype of 'values' is incorrect. Must be 'datetime64[ns]'. Got object instead.
```

Comment: copied your code exactly, ran without issues. What is the full traceback for your error?

Comment: Ran without issues too.

Comment: Found the issue. pandas wasn't updated to the latest version. upgrading via pip install pandas --upgrade solved it